# Error: Property type is missing on the socket message

Tags: angular, websocket, ngxs

I am using `Ngxs WebSocketPlugin` in the angular application and trying to connect the socket with the following syntax:

```
this.store.dispatch(new ConnectWebSocket({url, typeKey:'event'}));
```

While listening to the socket, I am getting the below server object via socket event:

```
{
    "event": "chat-state-change",
    "payload": {
        "changeInitiatedFrom": "message-marked-read",
        "patientChatState": {
            "__v": 0,
            "_id": "6281f4859bfa6d002a00adfb",
            "clinic": "60a7892aeb945000292c56d8",
            "createdAt": "2022-05-16T06:51:49.385Z",
            "id": "6281f4859bfa6d002a00adfb",
            "patient": {
                "_id": "6281f464014ec5001f552401",
                "firstName": "Himesh",
                "gender": "male",
                "id": "6281f464014ec5001f552401",
                "lastName": "Kumar",
                "mrn": "sdfasdf"
            },
            "primaryCareprovider": "627cc522088361001fc9b51a",
            "program": "60a7837502a6280029dea078",
            "readIndex": 9,
            "site": "60a789b602a6280029dea07d",
            "twillioChannelName": "chat-group-patient-careProvider-6281f464014ec5001f552401",
            "unreadCount": 0,
            "updatedAt": "2022-05-31T16:29:31.400Z"
        }
    },
    "broadcastType": "user",
    "users": null
}
```

Now I am getting the error in the console:

```
Error: Property type is missing on the socket message
    at Object.next (ngxs-websocket-plugin.js:296:1)
```

.
As per documentation, we can pass custom **typeKey** in **ConnectWebSocket()** method but even after passing the typeKey value 'event', it is taking default value 'type'.

Let me know if I need some improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

Pass the **typeKey** in the root module, it will work.

```
NgxsWebsocketPluginModule.forRoot({
      typeKey: 'event'
});
```